# problem loading image in event badge and template

Tags: images

i got a problem uploading image when creating template massage for event or  even badges.

For exemple when try to add an image to my event badges like in this pic :

[image]

and i click on the field image (red arrows)a popup window like this show up:

[image]

but when i double click the image it doesn't load to my field (neither png or jepg).

This problem occurs even when i try adding image with ckeditor (imce).

Can u please help me?

Drupal 7.67

civiCRM 5.15.0

kcfinder 3.12

my skills: definitely not a developper, no coding skills. just some html and css knowledge

THANK U